# Design pattern for processes reporting that they're done (in React)

Tags: design-patterns, reactjs

I'm rendering a page in a web application.
The page requires several subcomponents to be initialized and populated with data before the UI is rendered.

Let's say I have 3 subcomponents called `compA`, `CompB` and `compC` that need to be initialized with data before the component `UserView` can be rendered and displayed to the enduser.

How would I go about telling `UserView` that it can be rendered?
I'll use React components as an example but really I'm looking for a general solution that would be preferred to solve this type of problem (see explaination below code):

```
var UserView = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        readyToRender: false
    };
  },

  componentWillMount: function() {
    initComp("A");
    initComp("B");
    initComp("C");
  },

  initComp(component): function() {
    // do stuff
    reportReady(component);
  },

  render: function() {
    if (this.state.readyToRender) {
        return (
            <div>
            <CompA data={this.state.compAdata} />
          <CompB data={this.state.compBdata} />
          <CompC data={this.state.compCdata} />
          </div>
        );
    } else
        return false;
  }
});
```

For those unfamiliar with React:
`getInitialState` is called once to set the initial state of `UserView`.
`componentWillMount` is called once before rendering `UserView`, before `render`.
`render` is called whenever the state of `UserView` has changed and the component needs to be re-rendered.

Is this design pattern preferable to solve this problem?
Furthermore, how would I go about implementing `reportReady(component)` and how should I store the results? (Maybe as an array of booleans?)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a better way to invoke `initComp` with array, just like this:

```
  componentWillMount: function() {

    // note: initComp take arrray as argument
    initComp(["A", "B", "C"]);

  },

  // initComp take arrary as argument now
  initComp: function(components) {

    // reportReady function
    let reportReady = components => {

        let initTasks = components.map(component => {

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                // do stuff here,
                // initialize each component

            });
        });

        return Promise.all(initTasks);
    }

    // invoke reportReady
    reportReady(components).then(/* do what you want with result, you can store them in somewhere else */);
  },
```